# validation input time at 09 PM - 11 PM (laravel)

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

How to make validate input time at between 09 PM - 11 PM ?

it works with this code
'''

```
if ( empty($tanggal->tanggal) || empty($ruangan->r_meeting) || empty($mulai->mulai) && empty($selesai->selesai) ) {

    $save            = New Meet();
    $save->user_id   = Auth::User()->id;
    $save->nohp      = $request->get('nohp');
    $save->peserta   = $request->get('peserta');
    $save->agenda    = $request->get('agenda');
    $save->bagian    = $request->get('bagian');
    $save->r_meeting = $request->get('r_meeting');
    $save->tanggal   = $request->get('tanggal');
    $save->mulai     = $request->get('mulai');
    $save->selesai   = $request->get('selesai');
    $save->status    = 1;
    $save->save();

    Alert::success('Booking Berhasil Di Simpan', 'Simpan Booking')->autoclose(3000);

    return back();

}else{

    Alert::error('Waktu dan ruangan meeting sudah dibooking', 'Error')->autoclose(3000);
    return back();
}
```

'''
in other case, i wanna input time at between 08 PM - 10 PM, it still saved, what I want should not be saved to the database, the rejection popup appears...

I need help..

thanks guys..

Answer (score 1):

Use Laravel's Validation, the `date` attribute.

```php
public function handleRequests(Request $request){
    $request->validate([
        'time' => 'required|before:11pm|after:9pm'
    ]);
}
```

This should be correct, as per the Laravel Doc's `before` and `after` [validation rules](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#available-validation-rules).